# How to manipulate wav file data in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, wav

I'm trying to read a wav file, then manipulate its contents, sample by sample

Here's what I have so far:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import math

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('xenencounter_23.wav')

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i][0] = math.sin(data[i][0])
    print data[i][0]
```

The result I get is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

etc

It is reading properly, because if I write `print data[i]` instead I get usually non-zero arrays of size 2.

Answer (score 16):

The array `data` returned by `wavfile.read` is a numpy array with an *integer* data type.  The data type of a numpy array can not be changed in place, so this line:

```
data[i][0] = math.sin(data[i][0])
```

casts the result of `math.sin` to an integer, which will always be 0.

Instead of that line, create a new floating point array to store your computed result.

Or use `numpy.sin` to compute the sine of all the elements in the array at once:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('xenencounter_23.wav')

sin_data = np.sin(data)

print sin_data
```

From your additional comments, it appears that you want to take the sine of each value and write out the result as a new wav file.

Here is an example that (I think) does what you want.  I'll use the file 'M1F1-int16-AFsp.wav' from here: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples.html.  The function `show_info` is just a convenient way to illustrate the results of each step. If you are using an interactive shell, you can use it to inspect the variables and their attributes.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

def show_info(aname, a):
    print "Array", aname
    print "shape:", a.shape
    print "dtype:", a.dtype
    print "min, max:", a.min(), a.max()
    print

rate, data = wavfile.read('M1F1-int16-AFsp.wav')

show_info("data", data)

# Take the sine of each element in `data`.
# The np.sin function is "vectorized", so there is no need
# for a Python loop here.
sindata = np.sin(data)

show_info("sindata", sindata)

# Scale up the values to 16 bit integer range and round
# the value.
scaled = np.round(32767*sindata)

show_info("scaled", scaled)

# Cast `scaled` to an array with a 16 bit signed integer data type.
newdata = scaled.astype(np.int16)

show_info("newdata", newdata)

# Write the data to 'newname.wav'
wavfile.write('newname.wav', rate, newdata)
```

Here's the output.  (The initial warning means there is perhaps some metadata in the file that is not understood by `scipy.io.wavfile.read`.)

```
<snip>/scipy/io/wavfile.py:147: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  WavFileWarning)
Array 'data'
shape: (23493, 2)
dtype: int16
min, max: -7125 14325

Array 'sindata'
shape: (23493, 2)
dtype: float32
min, max: -0.999992 0.999991

Array 'scaled'
shape: (23493, 2)
dtype: float32
min, max: -32767.0 32767.0

Array 'newdata'
shape: (23493, 2)
dtype: int16
min, max: -32767 32767
```

The new file 'newname.wav' contains two channels of signed 16 bit values.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `np.sin(...)`. That's definitely the way to go, and it'll be *way* faster.

Comment: Thanks. I tried saving the sine values into another array (or technically a list), but when writing I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

Comment: @Jamil, I think you'll want to familiarize yourself with the basics of numpy arrays (e.g. http://www.engr.ucsb.edu/~shell/che210d/numpy.pdf, or http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial, or any other of the many numpy tutorials out there).  Without seeing what you did, I can't solve that problem.

Comment: I was just looking in to them. I suppose I need to convert a list to a numpy array. What I did was this: `for i in range(len(data)):
    data2.append([math.sin(data[i][0]), math.sin(data[i][1])])` with an initialized list data2, then I wrote `scipy.io.wavfile.write('newname.wav',rate,data2)`, with `rate` being the original rate from reading the original file

Comment: @Jamil: I've updated my answer.  Note that there are *no* python loops in my code.  All the numpy operations are vectorized.  You'll learn more about that if you work through one of the numpy tutorials.

Comment: This is very useful. However, in the future I plan on doing a variety of calculations to the samples, so using arrays will be really helpful, if not necessary. However, I'll probably use the numpy library as well, so +1

Comment: Can wave delete non-data somehow, or how can we inspect the non-data?

Comment: @LordPumplekin Instead of continuing such a discussion in the comments, it would be better to create a new stackoverflow question.